# Angular - Set css dynamically - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I'm trying to set some css properties, by querying an element's height.

I'm doing the following:

```
<div class="floor" *ngFor="let floor of floors">
    <div class="floor-number-container" #floorNumber [ngStyle]="{ 'left.px' : - floorHeight - 20 }">
        <div class="floor-number" [ngStyle]="{'width.px' : floorHeight}">
            {{ floor }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And inside the class:

```
@ViewChildren('floorNumber') floorNumbers: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.floorHeight = this.floorNumbers.first.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
}
```

It works, but I got the following error:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'left.px: -20'. Current value:
>   'left.px: -64'.

And I have no idea how I should tackle this problem to avoid that error. Is it possible to tell `[ngStyle]` to do nothing until `floorHeight` get a value ?

EDIT:

I fixed it by doing this:

```
setTimeout(() => this.floorHeight = this.floorNumbers.first.nativeElement.offsetHeight, 0);
```

But I don't like that kind of hack

Comment: before setting flootHeight, run change detector like this `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` , but you should type in your constructor like this `constructor(private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef)`

Comment: Still getting the error :/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to remove the error by doing this:

```
setTimeout(() => this.floorHeight = this.floorNumbers.first.nativeElement.offsetHeight, 0);
```

If anyone has a cleaner way, feel free to share it !